# C++ append unsigned char to wstring

Tags: c++, append, wstring

I want to append an unsigned char to a wstring for debugging reasons.

However, I don't find a function to convert the unsigned char to a wstring, so I can not append it.

Edit:
The solutions posted so far do not really do what I need.
I want to convert 0 to "0". 
The solutions so far convert 0 to a 0 character, but not to a "0" string.

Can anybody help?

Thank you.

```
unsigned char SomeValue;
wstring sDebug;

sDebug.append(SomeValue);
```

Comment: This? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/widen

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct call for appending a char to a string (or in this case, a wchar_t to a wstring) is

```
sDebug.push_back(SomeValue);
```

[Documentation here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/push_back/).

To widen your char to a wchar_t, you can also use [std::btowc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/btowc) which will widen according to your current locale.

```
sDebug.push_back(std::btowc(SomeValue));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just cast your unsigned char to char:

```
sDebug.append(1, static_cast<char>(SomeValue));
```

And if you want to use operator+ try this:

```
sDebug+= static_cast<char>(SomeValue);
```

Or even this:

```
 sDebug+=boost::numeric_cast<char>(SomeValue);
```

Comment: I wanted to append "SomeValue", meaning it should be added to the end. Your code does not work for me, the value is just not added.

Comment: @tmighty See edits.May be this will help you.I don't have access to a compiler now.

Answer (score 0):

There's an overload of `append` that also takes the number of times to append the given character:

```
sDebug.append(1, SomeValue);
```

However, this will result in a conversion between `unsigned char` and `wchar_t`. Perhaps you want `SomeValue` to  be a `wchar_t`.

Comment: When I say    wstring wsSomeValue;
   wsSomeValue=std::btowc(SomeValue);
   sDebug+= wsSomeValue;  it adds 0 character to the wstring. However that is not what I want. I want to add the Zero character to the wstring, no a Null character.

Comment: I want to convert the digit 0 to a wstring :-)

Answer (score 0):

wstring has a constructor that takes a char. That would create a wstring from a char which you can then append.

Comment: There may be more elegant solutions, but my respone to a post "However, I don't find a function to convert the unsigned char to a wstring" surely does not deserve a down vote.  It's neither misleading or incorrect.  It may even lead him to search for string or wstring and find all associated methods with it.